# How does neo4j do basic storage structure

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases

What is the basic 'unit of storage' for the neo4j database engine? For example, for a relational database, it might be seen of as a row of data. What is the equivalent atomic unit in a graph database? Is it a connection, and if so, what type of 'metadata' is there attached to it? For example:

```
connection:   (A,B) # tuple
is_directed:  false
_meta:        # helper data for the user to know what the edge "AB" is
```

What if someone wanted to define "A" as an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a node can stand alone (without being connected to any relationships), neo4j cannot use a "connection" (ie, "relationship") as the single "basic unit of storage".

In fact, if you look in the [data directory](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations-locations) of a neo4j installation, you will see separate files for nodes, relationships, properties, indexes, relationship types, and so forth. So, those could be considered the "basic units" for neo4j.

Comment: thanks for this answer. Could you please describe or provide a link to the various elements you describe (node, relationship, etc.)

Comment: For an intro to neo4, you could start [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/introduction/). For a little info on the data files, see [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-data-on-disk/).